# Wordpress: Can not translate Month name (get_the_date) into different language?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have changed the language settings of wordpress unfortunately date codes still displayed in English. Following is the php code which renders date field:

```
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_date( 'd M')); ?>
```

I have tried to translate the date by modifying the code but it didn't solved the problem:

```
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_date(_e( 'd M'))); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that I didn't saved the language change on the dashboard language settings !!!..

(Dashboard >> Settings >> General Settings)

Now, when I saved my changed, it works perfectly!!